# Observable not being unsubscribed to causing memory leak at cleanup

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have an observable that's become quite complex as it is being composed of multiple other upstream observables.

When I run my e2e tests through Jest it basically hangs and cannot complete as the observable is not being cleaned up properly. What I also notice is that it will also at times continue logging that it is trying to restart one of the inner observables from the top of the stream after I have stopped the service (due to retry logic). But this is after the primary downstream observable has been unsubscribed to.

This seems quite confusing given that the main observable when subscribed to is what is causing the upstream observable to fire and start emitting values. So if that same observable is unsubscribed to shouldn't that cause that first observable to run its cleanup logic and complete?

A basic of example of how it looks:

```
function obsWebsocket(topic: string): Observable<Buffer> {
   return new Observable<Buffer>(obs => {
      const ws = new WebSocket('url')

      ws.on('message', (msg: Buffer) => obs.next(msg))

      ws.onclose = close => observer.error(new Error('close'))

      return () => {
        console.log('closing websocket')
        ws.close()
      }
   })
}

function handleMsg(data: Observable<Buffer>): Observable<ParsedMessage> {
   return data.pipe(
      retry(3),
      mergeMap(msg => {
         const parsed = parseMsg(msg)
         return of(parsed)
      })
   )
}

function getMessages(topic: string): Observable<ParsedMessage> {
   const messages = obsWebsocket(topic)
   return handleMsg(messages)
}

function transformData(stream: Observable<ParseMessage>): Observable<ValidData> {
   return stream.pipe(
      // data transformation logic
   )
}

function getStreamForTopics(topics: string[]): Observable<ValidData> {
   return from(topics).pipe(
      mergeMap(topic => {
         const obsStream = getMessages(topic)
         return transformData(obsStream)
      })
   )
}

function getDataByTopic(topics: string[]): Observable<Record<string, ValidData>> {
   const dataByTopic = {
     'A': ValidData,
     'B': ValidData,
     ...
   }

   return getStreamForTopics(topics).pipe(
      scan((obj, data) => {
         obj[data.topic] = data
         return obj
      }, dataByTopic)
   )
}

const subscription = getDataByTopic.subscribe(data => {
   // do stuff with data
})

cleanup() {
   subscription.unsubscribe()
}
```

so when the `cleanup()` function is run I'm not seeing `console.log('closing websocket')` run and it's left trying to retry the observable. I'm not really sure what is going wrong... Any help or advice to better understand this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is most likely correct (If we discard the numerus typos).

What's probably happening is that your socket is throwing an error thus not triggering the complete.

You can check that by subscribing to all callbacks :

```
const subscription = getDataByTopic(['']).subscribe(
  (next) => {
    console.log(next);
  },
  (e) => {
    console.log('error', e);
  },
  () => {
    console.log('completed');
  }
);
```